# How to use java object as a KEY in Redis?

Tags: redis

which is the best way to use a java object as key in Redis?
I was thinking of serializing the object (through FST or KRYO).
Is this the best way?
Should i use an hash?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea using object byte array as the key, because Redis has key size limited, and calculate byte array hash code as the real key, so you should using the unique key stand for the object, smaller key size can improve performance.

Comment: Just note, key/value size limit is 512MB.